# Is there a possibility in jenkins to run build only if something changed (in ClearCase SCM) from last build?

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

I need to build in jenkins only if there has been any change in ClearCase stream. I want to check it also in nightly or when someone choose to build manually, and to stop the build completely if there are no changes.

I tried the poll SCM but it doesn't seem to work well...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, you should monitor the update of a snapshot view and, if the log of said update reveal any new files loaded, trigger the Jnekins job.

You find a similar approach in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014775552).

---

> You don't want to do something like that in a checkin trigger. It runs on the users client and will slow tings down, not to mention that you'd somehow have to figure out how to give every client access to that snapshot view.
>
> What can work is a cron or scheduled job that runs lshistory and does something when it finds new checkins.

---

> Yes you could do this via trigger, but I'd suggest a combo of trigger and additional script.. since updating the snapshot view might be time-consuming and effect checkins...
>
> 1. Create a simple trigger that when the files you are concerned about are changed on a stream will fire..
>      The script should "touch/create" a file in some well-known network location (or perhaps write to a pipe)...
> 2. the other script could be some cron (unix) or AT (windows) job that runs continually or each minute and if the well-known file is there will perform the update of the snapshot view..
>      The script could also read the Pipe written to by the trigger if you go that route
>
> This is better than a cron job that has to do an lshistory each time.. but Martina was right to suggest not doing the whole thing in a trigger for performance and snapshot view accessability for all clients.. but a trigger to write to a pipe or write some empty file is efficient and the cron/AT job that actually does the update is effieicnet as it does not have to query the VOB each minute... just the file (or only after there is info on the pipe)..

Comment: I have a script checking for changes (parse the .updt file), but I want to start the job, then stop all further steps and abort the build so it number won't increment if there were no changes

Comment: I do agree with VonC. Your situation is one of the reasons we now work to enhance our reporter tool for ClearCase and let the users to run actions (such as a build) if there are significant events in the system: a change in particular file; new code lines (not just adding comment lines) and more. If you'd like to try it when it's ready, contact beta@gomidjets.com